# d3js nicely transition lines with added points

Tags: d3.js

Say I have a `path`  I created with `d3` something like:

```
line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveLinear)
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x);})
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

data = [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 5, y: 5}, {x:10, y:10}];

myLine = svg.append("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("d", line);
```

This makes a nice diagonal line from 0 to 10.  Now if I update my data to make some changes and add some points:

```
data = [{x: 1, y: 1}, {x:2, y:3}, {x: 6, y: 7}, {x:9, y:9}];
```

And update my line

```
myLine.datum(data).transition().duration(1000).attr("d", line);
```

It gives a weird transition where it slides the existing path to fit the first three points of the new path and awkwardly adds the final point to the end.

Similarly, if I update it to have fewer points, it shortens the line and then slides the remainder over, instead of just reshaping the line where it is.

I understand *why* this happens, but I'm wondering if there's a way to create a more smooth transition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at this [page](https://bocoup.com/blog/improving-d3-path-animation) and this [github](https://github.com/pbeshai/d3-interpolate-path)

```
.attrTween('d', function () { 
    return d3.interpolatePath(line(data), line(data2)); 
});
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hx2ktodf/)